# Equation of Plane by using its parametric equations

Tags: calculus, parametric, plane-curves

The function $r(t)$ traces a circle. Determine the radius, center, and plane containing the circle parametrized as $ r(t)=−6i+ (9\cos(t))j+ (9\sin(t))k.$  Enter the equation of the plane in the format $ax+by+cz+d=0.$

I already found the radius $(r = 9)$ & the center $(-6, 0, 0)$ but I don't know how to find the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the format $ax+by+cz+d=0$, the normal vector to the plane is $(a,b,c)$,

and $(a,b,c)\cdot(x,y,z)+d=0$ for any point $(x,y,z)$ in the plane.

$(a,b,c)$ will be normal to any vector in the plane,

say the vector from the center to any point on the circle.

Therefore, you could take vectors from the center to two points on the circle,

and take their cross-product to get a vector normal to the plane.

That would give you an answer for $(a,b,c)$,

and then you could plug in values $(x,y,z)$ of a point in the plane (on the circle) to solve for $d$.

Alternatively, you could simply recognize that the $x$-component of $r(t)$ has only one value,

and that defines a plane.